# How to add post type in masonry posts elementory widget

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, widgets, query, post-type

When I try to create a website using Wordpress 5.2.2. I found a widget called **Masonry Posts** in Elementor Panel. But when I added the widget and checked there is no option to choose the post type. We can only change the category. The category also belongs to Default taxonomy, not custom post types taxonomy. So I can't add my posts from the custom post type(Demos).

After googling I found this one. https://developers.elementor.com/custom-query-filter/. But the query doesn't work.

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
    // Here we set the query to fetch posts with
    // post type of 'demo'
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'demo' ] );
} );
```

Anybody, please explain how to add custom post type using this widget or, how to create a widget like this or suggest any widget we can manage everything like this. I have checked different widgets but most of them have featured image while listing. My post type doesn't have any featured image. So I want to disable featured image. Also, I need to add custom fields from posts to the widget.

Answer (score -1):

I got a plugin [Elementor Addon Elements](https://wordpress.org/plugins/addon-elements-for-elementor-page-builder/) having the features which I mentioned in the question.

Any other answers for this issue are acceptable.